# What is the best way to put servlet files in Eclipse using Maven and Tomcat?

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, servlets

I'm using Eclipse with Maven and Tomcat for web application development. From some Tomcat tutorials (without using Maven), I understand that a servlet has to be put under the `webapps\{yourweb}\WEB-INF\classes\` folder and compile it into `.class` file. However, it seems not to be the best practice to do so in Eclipse with Maven. May anyone suggest what is the best place to put the servlet files?

Currently, I create servlet files through `New -> Servlet` in Eclipse and put them under `src/main/java/servlets`. It works, but I have no idea where the compiled `.class` files have gone after I start the server (I suppose the servlets are compiled into `.class` files when starting the server), and they are not under `Deployed Resources/webapp/WEB-INF`.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correctly. If you want to see the directory structure on server, export a war file from eclipse and deploy it on server(tomcat). It will create the / directory for your project in webapps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May you point out where are the compiled `.class` files? Merry Christmas :)